# Feedback control system in gravitational wave detectors

Tags: resource-recommendations, gravitational-waves, signal-processing, gravitational-wave-detectors

I am preparing for a seminar on ground-based gravitational wave detectors. One topic I have very little idea about is feedback control systems. I have a basic knowledge of it, but I need to read some articles about it. Please let me know if you can provide me with some articles on this topic.

Comment: [Feedback and Control Systems](https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/page/feedback)

Comment: [An overview of the LIGO Control and Data Acquisition System](https://accelconf.web.cern.ch/ica01/papers/tubi001.pdf) [PDF]

Comment: There are some links in [How are LIGO mirrors cooled?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235987/37364)

Comment: [This classic book by Saulson](https://www.amazon.com/Fundamentals-Interferometric-Gravitational-Detectors-Second-dp-981314307X/dp/981314307X/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) covers many topics relevant to gravitational wave interferometers such as LIGO, including feedback.